# Script running only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a side menu that opens and closes from the left when you press the menu button. 
Got the css, html code running properly but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with the script. It works perfectly but only once: When I press the menu button it comes out, press it again and it goes back just as intended. The problem is if I press it again it shows and it goes back by itself. Can anyone help me?
Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.menu-icon').click(function(){
    $('#navigator').animate({left:'0px'},200);
    $(this).animate({left:'250px'},200);
    $('.menu-icon').click(function(){
        >$('#navigator').animate({left:'-250px'},200);
        >$(this).animate({left:'0px'},200);
}); 
});
>});
```

Comment: You are binding a click handler *inside* the existing click handler. So on the second click both handlers will run and a *third* will be bound. On the third click all three will run and a *fourth* will be bound.

Comment: As a general guide, you would seldom register event handlers inside click event handlers (and when you do you would turn them on and off instead).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have placed a click handler inside a click handler so it will run multiple times. Twice first time, then three times, then four times etc.

You need to have a single handler and decide how to animate *based on the current state of the element*. e.g. something like the following (not tested):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.menu-icon').click(function () {
        if ($('#navigator').css("left") != "0px") {
            $('#navigator').animate({
                left: '0px'
            }, 200);
            $(this).animate({
                left: '250px'
            }, 200);
        } else {
            $('#navigator').animate({
                left: '-250px'
            }, 200); > $(this).animate({
                left: '0px'
            }, 200);
        }
    });
});
```

I would suggest testing the "current state" using a class you toggle on the element as testing css values is notoriously unreliable during animation.

e.g. something like:

```
    if ($('#navigator').toggleClass("open").hasClass("open")) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. Only one correction:   if ($('#navigator').css("left") == "-250px")  (the menu starts out hidden).

Comment: Let me know any corrections so I can update. I would recommend the second option.

Comment: I just started learning jquery. I will do some research to try the second method later. Thanks again. ps: I can't upvote the answer because I don't have enough points. I only could choose the answer as a thank you. edit: It works with !=0px too.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are attaching the click event listener two times. One normal and one after clicking, thats why its happening use jquery toggle

or use in this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.menu-icon').click(function(){
     var navigator = $('#navigator');
     if(navigator.offset().left == 0)
     {
        navigator.animate({left:'-250px'},200);
        $(this).animate({left:'0px'},200);
     }
     else
     {
        navigator.animate({left:'0px'},200);
        $(this).animate({left:'250px'},200);
     }

  });
});
```

Comment: jQuery has no left() method.

Comment: Thanks, it will be offset().left

Comment: Better. You still have a typo (`navigatore`) but down-vote removed :)

Comment: Thanks again TrueBlueAussie